# Why does the C++ standard handle file seeking the way it does?

Tags: c++, file, language-lawyer, seek, c++20

C++ uses the `streamoff` type to represent an offset within a (file) stream and is defined as follows in [stream.types]:

> `using streamoff = implementation-defined ;`
>
> The type streamoff is a synonym for one of the signed basic integral types of sufficient size to represent the maximum possible file size for the operating system. 287)
>
> 287) Typically long long.

This makes sense because it allows for seeking within large files (as opposed to using `long`, which may be only 32 bits wide).

[filebuf.virtuals] defines `basic_filebuf`'s function to seek within a file as follows:

> `pos_type seekoff(off_type off, ios_base::seekdir way, ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) override;`

`off_type` is equivalent to `streamoff`, see [iostreams.limits.pos]. However, the standard then goes on to explain the function's effects. I'm irritated by the very last sentence, which requires a call to `fseek`:

> *Effects*: Let `width` denote `a_codecvt.encoding()`. If `is_open() == false`, or `off != 0 && width
>   <= 0`, then the positioning operation fails. Otherwise, if `way != basic_ios::cur` or `off != 0`, and
>   if the last operation was output, then update the output sequence and write any unshift sequence.
>   Next, seek to the new position: if `width > 0`, call `fseek(file, width * off, whence)`, otherwise
>   call `fseek(file, 0, whence)`.

`fseek` accepts a `long` parameter. If `off_type` and `streamoff` are defined as `long long` (as suggested by the standard), this could lead to a down conversion to `long` when calling `fseek(file, width * off, whence)` (leading to potentially hard to diagnose bugs). This calls into question the whole rationale for introducing the `streamoff` type in the first place.

Is this intentional or a defect in the standard?

Comment: defect looks like.

Comment: I think I see that gcc libstdc++ uses [fseeko64](https://github.com/avsm/src/blob/master/gnu/gcc/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/stdio_sync_filebuf.h#L171).

Comment: Offhand, it doesn't look like `seekoff` necessarily *uses* `fseek` under the hood. Rather, the (presumably familiar?) behavior of `fseek` is used to explain what `seekoff` is doing.

Comment: @jjramsey This was my impression as well. However, the way it is phrased seems to suggest a requirement rather than an explanation.

Comment: That is in a para describing *effects*.

Comment: @jjramsey I agree that the "Effects" part can reasonably be interpreted to mean that it doesn't actually have to call `fseek` as long as it does something with the same effect. But `fseek` with an offset less than `LONG_MIN` or greater than `LONG_MAX` has no effect, so the explanation is at best incomplete, at least for implementations where `streamoff` is wider than `long`.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the conclusion that you're drawing from this, that there is a mismatch between C++ streams and `fseek` that will lead to runtime bugs, is incorrect. The situation seems to be:

1. On systems where `long` is 64 bits, `streamoff` is defined as `long`, and the `seekoff` function invokes `fseek`.
2. On systems where `long` is 32 bits but the OS supports 64-bit file offsets, `streamoff` is defined as `long long` and `seekoff` invokes a function called either `fseeko` or `fseeko64` that accepts a 64-bit offset.

Here's s snippet from the definition of `seekoff` on my Linux system:

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_LFS
    if (!fseeko64(_M_file, __off, __whence))
      __ret = std::streampos(ftello64(_M_file));
#else
    if (!fseek(_M_file, __off, __whence))
      __ret = std::streampos(std::ftell(_M_file));
#endif
```

LFS stands for [Large File Support](http://www.opengroup.org/platform/lfs.html).

Conclusion: While the standard suggests a definition for `streamoff` that ostensibly conflicts with the requirement that `seekoff` invoke `fseek`, library designers understand that they must call the variant of `fseek` that accepts the full range of offsets that the OS supports.

Comment: @ypnos I didn't downvote and I find this answer useful. I guess someone downvoted because it misses the point. The problem isn't that there are sane implementations which ignore the standard in this regard, the problem is that the standard needs to be ignored in order for the implementation to be sane.

Comment: `The situation seems to be:` - The situation is that the implementation is not allowed not to call `fseek` in `seekoff`. It must call `fseek`, it doesn't, [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf#virtuals-13) says it has to. I can argue that this implementation is invalid. I believe it doesn't answer the question. Och, found [llvm](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/fstream#L950), it calls `fseeko`.

Comment: Just as an FYI, VC++ calls `_fseeki64` for this function; which also seems to violate what the standard says.

Comment: This is a case of the implementers realizing the problem and ignoring the standard.  I'm glad they did, but the standard really needs to be fixed.

Comment: Some people are taking the standard too literally. It's not demanding that the implementation literally call a function called `fseek`. Elsewhere the standard describes something as being "as if by calling `fseek(...)`." If it cared so much about literally calling `fseek`, that statement would be different. Seriously, what would you do, if you were implementing a C++ library? Would you insist on calling `fseek` with the lower 32 bits of a 64-bit file offset, because a document tells you to? Would your customers thank you for that?

Comment: If we take the standard literally, it would mean that implementing the C++ I/O library on a system that just doesn't have an API called `fseek` would be impossible. I don't think that was the intent.

Comment: If taking the standard literally leads to absurd conclusions, that's a sign that the standard needs to be corrected.It doesn't mean that it's a major problem, particularly if implementers apply common sense rather than doing exactly what the standard says. (`fseek` is part of the C standard library, and therefore part of the C++ standard library, so your second comment doesn't apply.) If the standard elsewhere uses the phrase "as if by calling `fseek()`, then the obvious fix is to use that same phrase here, though I'd also want a note clarifying that `fseek`'s limitations don't apply.